# Fetch child array elements one by one from a mongodb collection

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb collection like

```
{
    {"_id":1,"cust_id": 1,"urls":["www.a.com","www.b.com","www.c.com"]},
    {"_id":2,"cust_id": 2",urls":["www.x.com","www.y.com","www.z.com"]},
    {"_id":3,"cust_id": 3",urls":["www.1.com","www.2.com","www.3.com"]}
}
```

and I need to fetch each url like www.a.com.

I am able to get "urls": `["www.a.com","www.b.com","www.c.com"]`

`using db.collection.find({"cust-id": 1},{"_id":0})`

but I just need `www.a.com` and then `www.b.com` and so on.

Comment: iterate through this array you'll get that

Comment: Shouldn't `{"_id" = 0}` be `{"_id" : 0}` ?

Comment: @HassanImam   yes you are right, I have edited it now.

Comment: Store the output from the query execution then using `array#forEach` iterate all `urls`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.mycoll.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $match: {
                cust_id: 1
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: '$urls'
            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $project: {
                urls: 1
            }
        }

    ]


);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate with `async` library

```
db.collection.find({"cust-id": 1},{"_id":0})
   .exec(function(err,users){

         async.each(users.urls , function(result,callback){
              console.log(result); // check console.log(result)
         });
   });
```